# Using MLS package and Kotex package together

Tags: scripts

I asked a similar question before but would like to rephrase it to make the point clearer.

I would like to use the package MLS (to type Mongolian and Manchu scripts) and Kotex (to type Chinese-Japanese-Korean scripts) together. But when I run them together, some Mongolian characters do not appear properly.

For example, when I run:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mls}

\begin{document}

\bicig{bicik-i}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Which is what is desired. But when I add the kotex package, I get:

[image]

where "i" does not appear properly.

Is there any way I could run both packages properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I get the same output with and without `kotex` (that should be loaded before `mls` in order to avoid an “option clash” error).